# Refactoring repeated code with specific implementations?

Tags: python, json, oop, refactoring

I've got a method that has to loop through a dataset and then performs a specific lookup:

```
def lookup_x(findings, count, client, value):
    for finding in findings["Findings"]:
        for resource in finding["Resources"]:
            if finding["Status"] == "DEPLOYED":
                if count == 0:
                    publish(
                        finding["Title"],
                        resource["Id"],
                        finding["Status"],
                    )
            else:
                if count == 0:
                    publish(
                        finding["Title"],
                        resource["Id"],
                        finding["Status"],
                    )
                try:
                    lookup = client.SPECIFIC_LOOKUP_METHOD(SPECIFIC_VARIABLE_NAME=some_value)
                    # some_value is based on the specific lookup method
                    # it might be resource["Id"] or resource["Id].split(":")[3] ect. 
                    if value in json.dumps(lookup["SPECIFIC_KEY_NAME"]):
                        return False
                except ClientError:
                    pass
    return True
```

Every line except for what's in the `try/except` is always the same. Right now I've got the same method lookup_x() repeated 25 times with different logic within the `try/except`. What's the easiest way to refactor this so I only require one method where I can override the logic within that small snippet?

It'd be handy if I could do something like import the specific method name with all the parameters it requires but I know this isn't possible:

```
def lookup_x(value, client, findings, count, SPECIFIC_LOOKUP_METHOD(SPECIFIC_VARIABLE_NAME=some_value):
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the specific method with a set of fixed parameters using [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial).

`functools.partial` will take:

- a *callable* object (a function, or a class instance that implements `__call__`)
- any number of positional arguments
- any number of keyword arguments

and will return a new callable object that has those positional & keyword arguments set. This is often referred to as "binding" arguments.

```py
import functools

def foo(arg1, arg2, kwarg1="kw1", kwarg2="kw2"):
    print(f"arg1: {arg1}, arg2: {arg2}, kwarg1: {kwarg1}, kwarg2: {kwarg2}")

partial_foo = functools.partial(foo, 1234, kwarg2="bound-kw2")

# arg1: 1234, arg2: arg2, kwarg1: kw1, kwarg2: bound-kw2
partial_foo("arg2")
```

---

Here's a quick toy example that roughly follows the layout of `lookup_x`, above, if you wanted to play with different methods of binding arguments to functions.

```py
import functools


def lookup_x(value, lookup_func):
    # Code that runs every time...
    print(f"got value: {value}")

    try:
        # Notice here how we call `lookup_func` without any arguments!
        lookup_result = lookup_func()
    except RuntimeError:
        print("oh no, lookup func failed")
    else:
        if value in lookup_result:
            print(f"found '{value}' in lookup result")
        else:
            print(f"didn't find '{value}' in lookup result")


def get_dogs():
    return ["labrador", "border collie", "chihuahua"]


def get_fish(color):
    return [f"{color} trout", f"{color} pike"]


class Client:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def get_things(self, num):
        return [f"{self.name}: {i}" for i in range(num)]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # I can pass a function that doesn't take any arguments directly to
    # lookup_x:
    lookup_x("labrador", get_dogs)

    # Using functools.partial, I can bind some or all arguments to that
    # function before I call it!
    get_red_fish = functools.partial(get_fish, "red")
    lookup_x("yellow trout", get_red_fish)

    # I can also use functools.partial to bind arguments to an
    # instance method:
    client = Client("foo")
    get_five_things = functools.partial(client.get_things, 5)
    lookup_x("foo: 3", get_five_things)
```